# Converting/ translating Excel Formula in SQL query

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, sql

i have a layer in QGIS "Network" with attribute table.  I want to compare columns rows from each columns and create ine and fill it based on result from comparison. Untill now I did it with help in Excel:
[image]

I'm looking for to this in QGIS with help of SQL query:

`SELECT t1.*,`

```
     CASE WHEN Rock_G_ID =
                `(SELECT Rock_G_ID`
                   ` FROM network t2`
               ` WHERE t2.rownum = t1.rownum - 1) THEN '1'`
     ELSE '-' END AS Class`
     FROM network t1`
```

This works for one column and can't get it for the both same time like the formula in Excel. How can I do this?

Comment: Try looking into window functions, such as lead() and lag(). Those functions respecively look at the previous row and the next row's value :)

Comment: @GHRF thank you for your suggestion , can you give me an example

Answer (score 1):

I Haven't had a chance to test this, but it should get you close...

```
 CASE 
    WHEN attribute(get_feature(  @layer_name,  "fid" ,  @row_number -1 ),  "Rock_G_ID" ) = "Rock_G_ID"
        THEN attribute(get_feature(  @layer_name,  "fid" ,  @row_number -1 ),  "NEWColumn" )
    WHEN attribute(get_feature(  @layer_name,  "fid" ,  @row_number -1 ),  "ID_G" ) = "ID_G"
        THEN attribute(get_feature(  @layer_name,  "fid" ,  @row_number -1 ),  "NEWColumn" ) + 1
    ELSE 
        1
 END
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer , i will test it tomorow